# div section clone by jquery

Tags: jquery

i am facing problem to create clone of my firstSection (div) and paste it on up to secondSection.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#firstSection").clone().prependTo("#secondSection");
   });
</script>

<table width="100%" border="1">
<div id="firstSection">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</div>

<div id="secondSection">
    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</div>
</table>
```

Comment: `<div>` element is not supposed to lay inside a `<table>`. `<td>` is fine, but table m m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you can't have `div` elements within a `table` (unless they're enclosed within a `td` or `th`, so this is probably the result of the browser correcting invalid mark-up, however if you use `tbody` instead of `div`, it *should* work:

```
<table width="100%" border="1">

    <tbody id="firstSection">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody id="secondSection">
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Assuming you want to copy only the contents of the `tbody`/`#firstSection` element, and not create multiply-nested elements:

```
$('#firstSection').clone().contents().prependTo('#secondSection');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6CehB/).

Comment: i want when the user click on button than more textfield will appear to add more data and create multiple records from one form to insert in mysql

Comment: Did you consider *asking* that question?